# VLC for iOS wants the right to delete *all* of your Google Drive files; is there a way to limit this to a folder?

Tags: vlc-media-player, google-drive

[image]

I would like to try out this app, but I don't want to give it the right to delete all of my files on Google Drive.

I would be okay with giving it this level of permission within a particular folder but not my entire drive.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Meta says that this is the site to ask questions about VLC. If there is a more appropriate site, please migrate the question to it and update the Meta question so that everyone asking questions about VLC will know where to go. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257903/298909

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That scope is defined by Google. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive

Some apps request full access so they can manage files across all of Drive, rather than just files that the app has created.

VLC is a well-known, trustworthy software. You can be confident that it won't delete anything you haven't told it to.

To answer your question: The scope is requested by the app. As far as I know, you can't edit specific properties of that scope.